# How is this an open cover for any of the projective complex spaces?

Tags: general-topology

A little confused how this set of equivalence classes forms an open cover. We'll start with the definition of an n-dimensional complex projective space:

Let $X=(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\backslash \{0 \}) / \sim$

Where $x\sim y$ iff $x=\lambda y$

$\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n=X/\sim$

Let's take an arbitrary element from our punctured complex metric space:

Let $z=(z_0,z_1,...z_n)$ $\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\backslash \{0 \}$

Denote $\bar{z}$ the equivalence class of $z$, then define the collection of points

$U_i=(\bar{z}|z_i\neq 0)$

Here's what I read that completely perplexes me:

$\{U_i|0\leq i\leq n\}$ (allegedly) forms an open cover of the projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$. How exactly can this be true? My first attempt at understanding was for $n=1$. In this case we essentially have two vectors, correct? In order to "cover" this projective plane would it not need to be a circle of points?

Comment: When $n = 1$ the two open sets in the cover are two copies of $\mathbb{C}$. In general they are copies of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: I think the text I was reading forgot to use the word collection then. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p : C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb CP^n$ denote the quotient map.

The sets $V_i = \{ z \in \mathbb C^{n+1} \mid z_i \ne 0 \}$ are open in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, thus open in $\mathbb C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ since $0 \notin V_i$. Clearly $\bigcup_{i=0}^n V_i = \mathbb C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. We have $U_i = p(V_i)$, thus the $U_i$ cover $\mathbb CP^n$.  We claim that $p^{-1}(U_i) = p^{-1}(p(V_i)) = V_i$ which proves that that $U_i$ is open in $\mathbb CP^n$.

The inclusion  $\supset$ is trivial. So let $z \in p^{-1}(p(V_i))$, i.e. $p(z) \in p(V_i)$. This means that $p(z) = p(w)$ for some $w \in V_i$, thus $z = \lambda w$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. But $w_i \ne 0$, hence $z_i = \lambda w_i \ne 0$ which shows $z \in V_i$.

Let us prove that each $U_i$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$.

1. The restriction $p_i : V_i \to U_i$ of $p$ is a quotient map. In fact. let $U \subset U_i$ such that $p_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $V_i$. We have $p_i^{-1}(U) = p^{-1}(U) \cap V_i = p^{-1}(U)$ because $p^{-1}(U) \subset p^{-1}(U_i) = V_i$. Since $V_i$ is open in $\mathbb C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, we see that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb C^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, thus $U$ is open in $\mathbb CP^n$. Hence $U$ is also open in $U_i$.
2. Let $\mathbb C^n_i$ denote the set of all $z \in \mathbb C^{n+1}$ such that $z_i = 1$. This is a complex hyperplane, in particular it is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb C^n$. Clearly $\mathbb C^n_i \subset V_i$. It therefore suffices to show that the restriction $q_i : \mathbb C^n_i \to U_i$ of $p_i$ is a homeomorphism. Define $r_i : V_i \to  \mathbb C^n_i, r_i(z) = \frac{1}{z_i}z$, which is a continuous map.  We have $(q_i \circ r_i)(z) = q_i(r_i(z)) = q_i(\frac{1}{z_i}z) = p(\frac{1}{z_i}z) = p(z) = p_i(z)$, i.e. $q_i \circ r_i = p_i$. Since $p_i$ is surjective, also $q_i$ must be surjective. It is also injective since $q_i(z) = q_i(z')$ (which is the same as $p(z) = p(z')$) means that $z  = \lambda z'$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Thus $1 = z_i = \lambda z'_i = \lambda 1 = \lambda$, therefore $z = z'$. This shows that $q_i$ is a continuous bijection. We shall show that $q_i$ is a quotient map which completes the proof since bijective quotient maps are homeomorphisms. So let $U \subset U_i$ be such that $q_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb C^n_i$. Then $r_i^{-1}(q_i^{-1}(U)) = (q_i \circ r_i)^{-1}(U) = p_i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $V_i$ and by 1. $U$ is open in $U_i$.